# Solving the advection equation with an absorbing boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, characteristics

## Setup:

A tool I have used as a tool to learn about stochastic processes has been to solve deterministic problems with stochastic machinery. For example, for a Brownian process with drift
$$ \dot{x} = V + \xi(t)$$
we have a Fokker-Planck equation
$$ \partial_t P(x,t|x_0) = (-V \partial_x + D \partial_x^2 )P(x,t|x_0).$$
If we turn off the diffusion and make the problem deterministic, we get a simple advection equation:
$$ (\partial_t + V \partial_x)P = 0$$
which has solution $P(x,t|x_0) = \delta(x-x_0-V t).$ So we have solved for the distribution of this deterministic process.

## Problem statement:

I would like to continue this way of thinking and get the (deterministic) first passage time distribution.
Therfore I want to solve $(\partial_t + V \partial_x)P(x,t|x_0)=0$ with the initial condition $P(x,0|x_0) = \delta(x-x_0)$, where $x_0<0$, and the absorbing boundary condition $P(0,t|x_0)=0$. I then want to compute the survival probability $S(t|x_0) = \int_0^t P(0,t|x_0)dt$, and hence the first passage time distribution from $x=x_0$ to $x=0$, via $f(t|x_0) = -\partial_t S(t|x_0)$. I anticipate the result
$$ f(t) = \delta(t- x_0/V)\Theta(-x_0),$$
but I am not sure how to obtain this.

## Attempt:

The advection equation $(\partial_t + V \partial_x)P(x,t|x_0)=0$ has characteristic curves $x_0 = x- Vt$.  Therefore I construct a solution
$$ P(x,t|x_0) = F(x - Vt).$$
This needs to meet the boundary condition
$$ F(-Vt) = 0$$
and the initial condition
$$ F(x) = \delta(x-x_0).$$
Here's the struggle. I don't know how to solve this pair of equations. I guess together they imply $\delta(-Vt - x_0) = 0,$ which is true if $-x_0 < Vt)$, but I'm really not sure here. Any advice?